# "My wife and I have been living here since we have been married." is the tense correct?

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-tense, present-continuous, present-participles

I want to make a sentence meaning that "we have been living here since the day of our marriage" but is the latter part of the sentence correct? 
"My wife and I have been living here since we have been married." 
Or should I write "since we married."

Thank you so much.

Comment: Gramatically, this suggest that you are now  **past** the point of having been married. Compare with, for example, 'since we have been eaten'. This sentence would only be correct if you got married in Vegas for a night, broke up the next morning but **then** moved in together.

Comment: The example of "since we have been eaten" does not fit in here. The word married has been used as an adjective.

Comment: The example of since we have been eaten does not fit in here. The word married has been used here as an adjective. Please see my answer below.

Comment: An alternative phrasing: "My wife and I have been living here *as long as* we have been married."

Answer (score 18):

It's very common to use a *get*-passive with *married*:

> My wife and I have been living here **since we got married**.

Most passives use *be*, but other verbs are possible as well: [Pullum lists](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2922) *come, get, go, have, hear, make, need,* and *see*.  Most of these are relatively uncommon and each one has idiosyncratic rules for when it's appropriate.  In this case *get* is appropriate because of *married*.

Your active version ("since we married") sounds less common but I think it's also acceptable.  Your perfect *be*-passive version ("since we have been married") doesn't sound idiomatic to me, and I would avoid it in this case.

Comment: +1 this is the simplest and most natural sounding to me. :) definitely what I (a native English speaker) would say

Comment: It is a nice answer. However, I think the phrase "get-passive with married is too difficult for learners of English language. Cannot we simply say it is get+adjective(married) phrase?

Comment: "Were married" would also work, though. It's less idiomatic, but not uncommon.

Comment: Trikly, you are right. I should have added it to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally in the English speaking world, marriages started when a official presiding at a wedding married a couple. So most people, when referring to the state of being married say 'since we were married' (by the official) rather than any of the forms which imply they were the active party. [Here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=since+we+got+married%2Csince+we+were+married%2Csince+we+married%2Csince+we+have+been+married&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csince%20we%20got%20married%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csince%20we%20were%20married%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csince%20we%20married%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csince%20we%20have%20been%20married%3B%2Cc0) an n-gram showing a few variations, which points to 'were married' being the most common.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should write "`Since we married`" because "Since" always followed by the past simple tense or the beginning  time of the verb.

Comment: What do you mean with "beginning time of the verb"? The _present_, as in "since when do we have this rule"?

Comment: @oerkelens "I've been swimming *since* **three in the afternoon**."  I believe that *three in the afternoon* in this example is what mohamed is describing as "the beginning time of the verb".

Answer (score 2):

*Since*, when used to indicate a duration, must be followed by a point-in-time reference; something has happened from that point in time until now.  *We have been married* indicates a duration rather than a point in time, so it is not suitable for being used with *since*.

Idiomatically speaking, I would suggest the phrase **"since the day we got married."**

Answer (score 1):

"Since" needs to be followed by an event (something you could describe by a single time and date). "We have been married" is a period of time (which you'd describe by a *range* of times/dates). You need to change the latter phrase to describe a point in time, not a period. "Since we got married" or "since we married" would both work.

Answer (score 1):

The most natural sounding phrases to a native english speaker are:

"My wife and I have been living here since we were married", and

"My wife and I have been living here since we got married"

The phrases with "since we have been married" and "since we have married" are grammatically incorrect.

The phrase with "since we married" is grammatically correct but awkward sounding.

Answer (score 0):

Magooda's answer is the best here.

What I would have said is "since we were married".

"Since we got married" also sounds natural.

"Since we married" is quite unnatural.  It sounds like something only a non-native speaker would say.

The rest just sound wrong.

You could say "since we have been married" with some other kind of phrase, though, e.g.
"My wife and I *have lived* here since we've been married".

But not "My wife and I have *been living* here since we've been married".